# Problem regarding means and 2d arrays on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my first ever post and I'm a non-native english speaker so please try to be patient to me!

I'm having a issue regarding the use of 2d arrays on Python. The thing is that I need a program able to receive student's names and their grades for a set number of subjects, student's names must be saved to an 1d array and their grades must be saved to another 1d array. Also the number of students and the name of each subject as their number must be issued by the user. My problem is that when it's the time to inform the user of the mean grade for each student and the mean grade for each subject the names don't add up with the resulting mean (I mean the resulting numbers are correct but they don't belong to the user/subject shown in the output). I was also told to not use any libraries other than statistics and those native to Python (it's a college assignment). I attach my code (it's in spanish, might translate it if needed) to anyone who is looking forward to help me. Thanks in advance!

```
    print("******Instituto Técnico de Contaduría*******")

m=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes de la carrera Técnico en Contaduría: "))
n=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de asignaturas: "))

est=[None]*m
mat=[None]*n
notasfinales=[[0.0 for x in range(n)] for y in range (m)]

for i in range (m):
      est[i]=str(input("Digite el nombre completo del(la) estudiante: "))

for j in range(n):
      mat[j]=str(input("Digite el nombre de la asignatura: "))


for i in range(m):
      print("*****Digite las notas del estudiante " + est[i] + "*****")
      for j in range(n):
          notasfinales[i][j]=float(input("Digite las notas de la asignatura " + mat[j] + "\n "))


print("****Promedio de notas por estudiante******")
for i in range(m):
    sumaFil=0
    for j in range(n):
        sumaFil= sumaFil + notasfinales[i][j]


    for i in range(m):
        pe=sumaFil/n

    print("El promedio del(la) estudiante " + est[i]  + " es " + str(pe))

print("****Promedio de notas por asignatura******")
for j in range(n):
    sumaCol=0
    for i in range(m):
        sumaCol= sumaCol + notasfinales[i][j]

    for j in range(n):
        pa=sumaCol/m

    print("El promedio de la asignatura " + mat[j]  + " es " + str(pa))
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your input, your expected output and what you got instead?

Comment: here are both https://imgur.com/a/Vp8qOZH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-using and overwriting the same variable name in your final code section. I highlight the issues here:

```
print("****Promedio de notas por estudiante******")
for i in range(m): # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< first usage of i
    sumaFil=0
    for j in range(n):
        sumaFil= sumaFil + notasfinales[i][j]

    for i in range(m): # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< overwrite i
        pe=sumaFil/n

    print("El promedio del(la) estudiante " + est[i]  + " es " + str(pe))

print("****Promedio de notas por asignatura******")
for j in range(n): # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< first usage of j
    sumaCol=0
    for i in range(m):
        sumaCol= sumaCol + notasfinales[i][j]

    for j in range(n): # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< overwrite j
        pa=sumaCol/m

    print("El promedio de la asignatura " + mat[j]  + " es " + str(pa))
```

Comment: Ty for the reply! What should I do then? That's the only way I figured out to relate the amount of interations and the name of the student that's going to be displayed on screen, as I need a mean grade for each student and there will always be "m" students in that specific order (if I'm not misunderstanding stuff). Should I use another variable instead?

Comment: @J.Aguilar I don't know why you would do this division in a loop to begin with.

Comment: Note that I'm a noob when it comes to arrays so it's possible I'm just mistaking everything, what would you do then?

Comment: Just remove the loops that I marked with 'overwrite' and put the `pe=` and `pa=` lines one indent level down.